# log4net - separate appender for a namespace

Tags: .net, log4net

I have been googling but haven't yet found an answer to my question.
I have my application and I have a client library connecting me to a database (in my case, it's RavenDb).

I would like RavenDb client messages to go to a separate file (meaning, all messages from instances of classes of Raven.Client.Xyz should be logged to raven-client.log file - *actions that client library performs, e.g. connecting to server, waiting for response, getting/updating documents, querying an index, etc.*, **not what my code does interacting with a client library**). How can I achieve that? I tried separate appender, but then RavenDb logs appear in my application logger too.

I'm using xml configuration and log4net version is 1.2.10

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I just checked and this solution works:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%utcdate [%thread] %-3level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="application.log" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%utcdate [%thread] %-3level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RavenClientFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="ravendb-client.log" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%utcdate [%thread] %-3level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="Raven.Client" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug" />        
        <appender-ref ref="RavenClientFileAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Sorry everyone, I *was* on the right track with this

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. Create a seperate appender, and then rather than grabbing the main logger, select a specific appender using code like the following:

```
ILog ravenLog = LogManager.GetLogger("RavenDbAppenderName");

ILog nonRavenLog = Logmanager.GetLogger("Other appender name");
```

And then pass the appropriate `ILog` into each place in your code.

Comment: well, I suppose I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to log how my code uses RavenDb client - I want *what client itself is doing* to be logged (e.g. connecting to a server, getting/updating documents, waiting on response, etc.) I updated the question

Comment: @chester89 so wait, you want to redirect logs that the library you are using produces by itself to use a log4net appender?

Comment: not quite - RavenDb client knows how to write to logs, it just needs to be configured properly. see my answer